# TabNav disappears when using StackNav within it in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```
function TabNav() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName='home'
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => screenOptions(route, color),

                tabBarActiveTintColor: '#1579ac',
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#000',
                tabBarShowLabel: false,
                tabBarStyle: [
                    {
                        display: 'flex',
                    },
                    null,
                ],
            })}
        >
            <Tab.Screen name='home' component={Main} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Tab.Screen name='camera' component={Camera} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Tab.Screen name='base' component={Base} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Tab.Screen name='settings' component={Settings} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

const RootNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Group initialRouteName='TabNav'>
                <Stack.Screen name='TabNav' component={TabNav} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Apparaten' component={Apparaten} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Automation' component={Automation} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='News' component={News} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Logout' component={Logout} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Users' component={Users} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='EditApparaat' component={EditApparaat} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
            </Stack.Group>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
export default RootNavigator;
```

Whenever I swap Stack.screen the Bottom nav disappears. I know it is because the stack.screen that contains TabNav gets deactivated, but how can I go about fixing this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the Tabbar visible all the time, you need to organize your navigation structure the other way around. Each Tab contains a Stack (or a single screen) and the Tab.Navigator is the root navigator in your navigation container.

What is left for you to decide is which screen in your current `Stack.Group` is contained in which tab.

For the sake of simplicity, I have moved all the screen in a stack called `Main` which is the first Tab in your tab navigator. The workflow is the same for all tabs.

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export const Main = () => {
    return (
         <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name='Apparaten' component={Apparaten} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Automation' component={Automation} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='News' component={News} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Logout' component={Logout} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='Users' component={Users} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
                <Stack.Screen name='EditApparaat' component={EditApparaat} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

export const RootNavigator = () => {
    return (
            <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName='home'
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => screenOptions(route, color),

                tabBarActiveTintColor: '#1579ac',
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#000',
                tabBarShowLabel: false,
                tabBarStyle: [
                    {
                        display: 'flex',
                    },
                    null,
                ],
            })}
        >
            <Tab.Screen name='home' component={Main} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Tab.Screen name='camera' component={Camera} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Tab.Screen name='base' component={Base} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Tab.Screen name='settings' component={Settings} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};

const App = () => {

   return <NavigationContainer>
         <RootNavigator />
     </NavigationContainer>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense that thats the way to do it. You've really helped me a lot and I've got it functioning properly now. :)